# Catch all Force Closes and log with Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

Is there a way to intercept a FC before it exits my app so I can log it with Google Analytics? I understand that Force Closes come from uncaught exceptions but I don't want to surround every method with a Try/Catch.

I know the real answer is to write more defensive code but I thought that my code was already quite solid.  I was surprised to find a few new errors logged by users with things like OutOfMemoryExceptions and Admob blowing up.  I'd rather not have to rely on the kindness of users to send me errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).

That said, I'm not a fan of this, I'd rather have an app crash so users have the option to send a crash report. Sure, sucks short-term, but in the end, you'll get more detailed crash reports.

Comment: You can always re-throw the exception after you catch it and do your business. ;)

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks.  And I still intend to allow the app to crash when necessary but there may be a few more details that I can snag before it all goes to hell.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to catch the error log when APP FC's is using ACRA , Idk if works with google analytics, but its do with Google docs.

[ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Answer (score 0):

Include below code in you analytics.xml file,this will track all your uncaught exceptions with a description:

true

Read more about it on:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions